# DateAdd + DLookup

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am requesting some guidance to fix this problem I have been having while trying to edit the "AfterUpdate" event in my database. It seems to work fine on my local machine but when I try to implement it in the network database it doesn't work properly (occasionally puts in a random date in one of the fields, doesn't erase the date when I supply a new ID, etc.)

Here is the VBA Code I have:

```
Private Sub provider_surveyID_AfterUpdate()

provider_survey_dueDate = DateAdd("ww", 2, DLookup("completed_on",
 "qry_ProviderSurveyInfo", "provider_surveyID=" & provider_surveyID))
provider_survey_reminder2weeks = DateAdd("ww", 4, DLookup("completed_on", 
 "qry_ProviderSurveyInfo", "provider_surveyID=" & provider_surveyID))
provider_survey_reminder4weeks = DateAdd("ww", 6, DLookup("completed_on", 
 "qry_ProviderSurveyInfo", "provider_surveyID=" & provider_surveyID))

End Sub
```

The query is correct, joining the Survey ID to the appropriate participant to determine the original "completed_on" date that is used in the DateAdd functions.

Can you see any reason why it would not work as it does on local - removing dates when entering IDs currently not in use? Also, think it would be wise to use Nz(provider_surveyID,0) in this instance? I haven't implemented it yet as I wanted to make it work appropriately as it does on my local with no issues whatsoever - I enter for the ID, it populates; I enter 20 (not in use yet), it makes all dates null again.

Comment: Those are dates that are to be calculated based on the "completed_on" field from another table. The Provider Survey links to that one based on ID (Provider Survey is given an ID matching the provider's first participant - participant ID). The completed_on date is entered into a form and in an alternate form once user's enter in the ID I had the other date fields autopopulate, but wanted them displayed in case they needed to be overwritten, and then stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dlookups can be slow and tricky to use, it will also return random values when the Criteria isn't entered. I'm not sure on how your form is put together (I'm assuming it's a form), and this may be a partial answer:

```
Private Sub provider_surveyID_AfterUpdate()
Dim dtComplete as Date

If IsNull(provider_serveyID) then
    provider_survey_dueDate=""
    provider_survey_reminder2weeks=""
    provider_survey_reminder4weeks=""
Else
    dtComplete = DLookup("completed_on","qry_ProviderSurveyInfo", "provider_surveyID=" & provider_surveyID)
    provider_survey_dueDate=DateAdd("ww",2,dtComplete)
    provider_survey_reminder2weeks=DateAdd("ww",4,dtComplete)
    provider_survey_reminder4weeks=DateAdd("ww",6,dtComplete)
End if
End sub
```

Comment: I'll admit it's not a complete answer, but I thought it would be a good start to set a date var to remove any chance some type conversion and to set a single point of lookup failure. If it continues to not work on the network version, and the Dlookup is still suspect you can switch out the DLookup with a recordset. If both the Dlookup and the recordset don't work on the network then you can look at the underlying dataset.

Comment: I'd debug this by setting that returned date as a typed date var to make sure some strange implict type conversion isn't happending. You can add Debug.Prints for dtComplete to check the correct date is being returned.  Then if the problem is still recurring, switch out the Dlookup for a recordset to remove the possiblity of wierd Dlookup behavior. I'd also check for any other object triggering the AfterUpdate event unintentionally.

Comment: You can also add debug.print before setting the text fields from the DateAdd function to eliminate the chance that the DateAdd is performing correctly, but the text field isn't handling the value as anticipated.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I have got it working now! I appreciate the code and making it a variable. The majority of my background is in Perl and some SQL, so a lot of this VBA is new to me but starting to get the hang of it!

The only downside is if they enter an ID that isn't currently in use they receive an error message 'Invalid Use of Null'. Is there a way I can do an "If exists..." function within the "Else" statement? Does VBA have something similar to this? That way if it doesn't exist, it will just make everything null instead of showing an error.

Comment: In retrospect, using the query as where it pulls the date is a bad idea as the query would have to be ran after saving the ID and then reopening it and THEN it would populate the fields.
Can you do a query within a DLookUp? Such as "DLookup(completed_on, "SELECT..." ...) to make a virtual table, if you will?

Comment: The syntax is If {statement} Then, ElseIf {statement}, Else, End if. It wouldn't work in the case you mention as what you're seeing is an error message. It'd be a good idea to doa quick search on VBA If then loops and Error trapping.

Comment: You might be better served doing the lookup via a recordset. (line break at ;) Dim str as String; Dim rs as recordset; str = "Select Top 1 completed_on from ..." Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset str; Do While Not rs.EOF; dtComplete = rs!completed_on; loop;

Comment: Thanks a lot @KFleschner. Your help has been greatly appreciated! In order to do the query on the spot I've learned to do nested DLookups. However, it works when put into a label with a hardcoded ID, but in the AfterUpdate event it says there's a Data Type Mismatch? 
    `dtComplete = DLookup("completed_on", "tblPatientAssessments", "[assessment_point_id]=0 And [patient_id]=" & DLookup([id], [tblPatients], [QACT_ID] = provider_surveyID))` 
    This is only seen when including the assessment point; I removed this and it works, but it's needed as they have multiple surveys.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20280/discussion-between-blarsen-and-kfleschner)